# Reading file from another domain to update mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm about to start a project building a wp plugin and before I start I need some directions. The plugin will need to read the text file on a different domain and update MySQL on its own domain. Is this possible? I know that there is a way to update MySQL with text file but is it possible to do it across the domains?
Thanks,

Comment: That would depend on how the text file is available, via a web-server, etc. If you can access it via the web, there are different ways to read it and when you have the content in php, mysql does not care where it originally came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl is a PHP function/extension that can get the contents of a remote file for you

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Or simpler:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

However, your question is very general, the real "work" is in parsing the file, ie extracting it's contents in a usable format, and safe to insert into your database.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the task into the following:

1. Format the data on source domain so it would be easy to read on target domain. I suggest JSON or XML. Consider using some sort of keyword so that everyone can't grab that data, only you
2. Get the data via script with CURL or file_get_contents(). Script is likely to be run regularly, so put it on cron
3. Decode the data (data will be a string after the HTTP transfer) into array and use it to make SQL queries

Simple google search will help you with any details or feel free to ask further questions in comments